# Mouse cursor shaking when not using mouse (Lubuntu 22.04 LTA)

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I have recently installed lubuntu on my pc and everything works fine except the cursor, i have tried many things including using synclient but it just says "Synclient not found,but can be installed with "`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`" and it still doesnt work.

I have also tried using a wireless mouse and it doesnt work, i even tried turning off my trackpad, its definetly a software issue. Can anybody help?

Cheers.

Comment: You've not indicated which kernel stack you're using (*with Lubuntu the install media dictates this; 22.04 & 22.04.1 media used the GA kernel stack, and 22.04.2 & later media defaults to HWE*) as I'd likely boot a Lubuntu 22.04 media using the other kernel stack & see if it's different (ie. *live* test without installing anything). The only times I've had issues with a *pointer* that moves around strangely it was because I needed to charge or replace the mouse batteries (*could it be this?*). You

Comment: i apologise for not mentioning that I am reletivly (typo) new to linux, can you simplify?

Comment: Not a problem & sorry for lack of *easy* details.  If your system is fully upgraded, the command `uname -r` will tell you what kernel you're using. If your install was made with Lubuntu 22.04 or 22.04.1 media you'll be using the 5.15 kernel stack (*the GA kernel; it won't change*), if you used newer 22.04.2 media you'll find you're using 5.19 which is the current HWE kernel (*it'll upgrade to 6.2 next as you upgrade to 22.04.3*). By downloading a different Lubuntu ISO & writing it to thumb-drive; you can *try* it & see if it's different.. ie. without change to your system try the other kernel

Comment: FYI:   You'll get more details (*numbers etc*) from `uname` than I mention, only the first to sets of number matter in this case.. the other numbers & *generic|low-latency|etc* give more specifics as to what upgrades & kernel you're using; those aren't details I'm interested in.. ie. `uname -r` gives me `6.2.0-21-generic` where it's the 6.2 only I'm referring to here.